# Determining if a logical statement is false?

Tags: logic, integers

I'm currently working on some simple existential and universal quantification questions as a brush up for a discrete mathematics course and I'm having a bit of trouble remembering the method used to explain how a particular statement is true or false. Precisely, how do I show certain statements are in fact true or false, when there is an algebraic formula involved? I've had luck with a couple examples but right now I'm stumped on the following :

```
∀x ∈ Z, ∃y, z ∈ Z[x = 5y + 7z]
```

Should I solve the algebraic equation first, knowing that `z` and `x` are both integers? Or should I pay more attention to the individual quantifiers instead?

Comment: I'm not sure what the pedagogic intent is here, but since $\gcd(5,7) = 1$, the equation $5y+yz = 1$ has a solution (Bézout identity), hence there is a solution to the above.

Comment: I'm just trying to determine whether or not the statement is true or false, but that should put me on the right track so thanks!

Comment: Well, it is true, since $x = 5 (3x) + 7 (-2x)$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: I have a typo. above, I just wanted to point out that since $1=5y+7z$ has a solution, then $x=5y+7z$ has one too (this includes zero, of course).

Comment: But I'm not sure if this is what the OP was looking for...

Comment: Given *any* $x$, put $y = 3x$, $z=-2x$. Then, as @copper.hat has shown, we have $x = 5y+7z$, that is, the existence of $y, z$ such that $x = 5y+7z$. The same is true for every $x$. For each $x$, the choice of $y, z$ is determined because $y, z$ are are functions of $x \in \mathbb Z$.